# max-width in table td

Tags: html, css, html-table

I would like to set the max-width of my table td.

```
<td class="showwindow description">
    <div style="width:275px; white-space:nowrap; word-wrap:break-word; font-size:11px;">3 DRESS COVER AY (AGAVE PINK) 3 DRESS COVER AY (AGAVE PINK) 3 DRESS COVER AY (AGAVE PINK)</div>
</td>
```

But the text can't back to the line :

[image]

Comment: can you please post other codes too?? A http://jsfiddle.net/ would  be better

Comment: My css : http://pastebin.com/a2xmQSYe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove "white-space:nowrap" property from the div and set max-width.

Comment: Ok thank you, I have put white-space:normal only on this column and it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use this CSS code:

```
max-width:100px;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp

Comment: I have already try this but it doesn't works :( (on the sub div and on the td)

Answer (score 0):

you might have given width, but you have to give height to both td and div so that if text exceeds , it should fallback to next line, just giving only width wont do much